# Expressões idiomáticas para quando alguém está pedindo muita coisa

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, expressões-idiomáticas

Quais são as expressões (informais) mais comuns que se usam quando alguém está pedindo muitas coisas de você? Exemplo:

> Fulano: "Então, quero que você varra a casa, passe pano, lave o carro, a roupa também, e estenda-a no varal."
>
> Você: "Ufa Fulano, _________."

Uma que eu conhecia, mas não me lembro bem, era "Quer um café também não?" ou algo assim, mas não me lembro direito e não sei se é regional.

Comment: Eu conheço algumas que são bem chulas, tem problema colocá-las aqui?

Comment: @Hugo não, como eu disse, podem ser bem informais

Comment: Se as solicitações tiverem ar de urgência, aqui em SP podemos fazer uma brincadeira com a fabricação de pastel pois é algo que as pastelarias fazem bem rápido você grita um sabor e em poucos segundos está frito: "Vai um de queijo ou de carne?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas que são bem chulas e que eu só usaria com amigos que são muito próximos **e** que sei que não se ofenderiam com isso (mas nunca com minha mãe)

Lembrando que sou de São Paulo e pode ser que as expressões não sejam conhecidas ou tenham diferenças em outras regiões (dada a diversidade brasileira, é bem provável). Além disso, estou me baseando no contexto geral da pergunta (alguém pedindo muita coisa) ao invés do exemplo específico (minha mãe pedindo coisas, pois neste caso eu seria mais educado)

> Mamar na vaca você não quer?

Aparentemente a pessoa está pedindo tanta coisa que só falta querer mamar diretamente da vaca, sem intermediários.

> Quer mel na chupeta?

Similar ao anterior (lembrando que nesse caso "chupeta" é aquele acessório que os bebês colocam na boca, então só falta você querer uma chupeta lambuzada de mel - não sei de onde veio a expressão, mas a ideia é essa)

> E na bundinha, não vai nada?

Estão me pedindo tanta coisa que só falta quererem... acho que vocês entenderam

> Não quer também um (e leva uma das mãos perto da boca, fazendo um gesto que sugere sexo oral)

Similar ao anterior.

Mas nem tudo é baixo calão. Você também poderia dizer, de forma irônica, uma das expressões abaixo:

> - Só isso?
> - Tá pouco...
> - Mais alguma coisa?

Dito de forma irônica, a outra pessoa vai entender que você achou os pedidos dela excessivos.

Existe outra que já ouvi algumas vezes, embora eu não use com frequência:

> Fritas acompanham?

Ou seja, só falta você me pedir uma porção de batata frita.

---

Agora se fosse minha mãe, eu provavelmente responderia "Sim, claro!"

Comment: Eh pá, parece que andámos com as mesma ideias ao mesmo tempo!

Comment: Pois é, respondemos quase no mesmo instante..

Comment: Não há crise; e ficamos a saber que há coisas que se dizem em São Paulo que também se dizem em Portugal.

Comment: " 'mamar na vaca você não quer né' É usado quando a pessoa é muito folgada, e fica abusando da sua boa vontade: Sua irmã te pede um copo d'água. Você de boa vontade vai buscar. Quando vc traz, ela reclama que queria misturada do filtro e da geladeira. Eis que vc usa com tom de ironia: Ah! Mamar na vaca vc não quer, né?" "

Comment: @AndréLyra Eu já vi essa expressão ser usada em ambas as situações (a que vc descreveu e a que está na pergunta)

Comment: Usei aquelas velhas incógnitas da língua portuguesa para acabar com essa comoção de 'eu não falaria isso com minha mãe'

Answer (score 4):

Algumas expressões que conheço:

1. "não pode dar a mão que já quer o braço" <sub>[exemplo](http://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/como-dizer-a-gente-da-a-mao-eles-querem-o-braco-em-ingles-t16984.html)</sub>

> *Nossa, mãe, não posso te dar a mão que você já quer o braço!*

2. [*Brasil*] "lerê lerê" (tema da novela *A Escrava Isaura*), geralmente cantarolado <sub>[exemplo](http://chambolinho.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/selinho-engracado-pra-facebook.html)</sub>

> *lerê, lerê, lerê lerê lerê*

3. "que exploração" <sub>[exemplo](https://twitter.com/bfr_mil/status/839218621276639232)</sub>

> *Nossa, mãe, que exploração!*

Comment: Acho que a primeira é mais usada num contexto de "progressão". Ex: eu começo a fazer uma coisa, outra pessoa diz: "já que vc está fazendo isso, aproveite pra fazer mais isso, isso e isso". Aí eu usaria a expressão 1.

Comment: @Hugo Sim, concordo, mas não quis me apegar muito aos detalhes do contexto. Imaginei que mais respostas viriam - dada a natureza da pergunta - e tomei a liberdade de dar uma resposta mais genérica. Você acha que um esclarecimento é necessário? Pode propor uma edição se julgar cabível.

Comment: Entendi. Como a ideia era dar uma resposta mais genérica, acho que está ótimo assim. Mas agora fiquei com uma dúvida: se eu fosse editar, provavelmente adicionaria um parágrafo inteiro. Posso editar as respostas dos outros acrescentando tanta informação? Achei que fosse apenas para pequenos detalhes como formatação, ortografia, etc

Comment: @Hugo Pode. Na verdade, você pode sugerir a edição que você quiser. Se o usuário ou a comunidade discordarem, eles podem dar rollback. Em alguns casos, é até preferível acrescentar parágrafos inteiros, como quando o post precisa de exemplos, ou esquece de citar fontes, ou responde só com um link (o ideal é que a informação esteja no post), ou nos casos em que os comentários possuem informações do autor que deveriam estar no post. Em todos estes casos, é de bom tom escrever uma explicação bem completa e também deixar um comentário avisando.

Answer (score 3):

Se alguém me viesse com estes pedidos em excesso, como no teu exemplo:

> Então, quero que você varra a casa, passe pano, lave o carro, a roupa também, e estenda-a no varal.

Eu poderia responder com um das opção seguintes ou uma combinação delas:

> - Mais alguma coisa?
> - Só isso?
> - Tem a certeza que não se esqueceu de nada?

Isto vai numa linha irónica, como o teu “Quer um café também, não?” Mas esta do “café” seria mais apropriada se a mãe me tivesse pedido para lhe trazer coisas. Por exemplo, ela está sentada na varanda e pede:

> Sê um bom filhinho e traz-e o meu chapéu e óculos escuros que estão na sala. E já agora traz-me também o livro que está na minha mesinha de cabeceira, e um copo de água da cozinha.

Depois, uma que se ouve aqui em Portugal, mas que poderá ser preferível não usar com a mãe:

> Não queres também que te lave o rabinho (com água de rosas/malvas)?

Comment: Temos uma similar a esta última aqui no Brasil, mas achei a versão nacional desnecessariamente chula para uma resposta.

Comment: @RamonMelo Eh pá, agora tens que dizer! *Rabinho* em Portugal não é chulo; equivalente provavelmente a *bundinha* no Brasil. Claro que  com certas pessoa ou em certas situação é preferível abstermo-nos de sugerir lavar-lhes o traseiro, independentemente da palavra que se use.

Comment: O Hugo citou a versão nacional: "e na bundinha, não vai nada?" O problema não está no objeto, mas na _ação_ que está sendo sugerida. hehe

Comment: @RamonMelo - Ah, mas *lavar o rabinho* é mesmo 'lavar o rabinho'; não tem qualquer conotação sexual.

Comment: Sim, por isso que a versão brasileira é chula e a europeia, não. :)

Comment: @RamonMelo Eu tinha visto a resposta do Hugo, mas nem considerei *na bundinha, nada?* como versão de *lavar o rabinho*.